# Angular 6 app after refresh redirect to root

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-ui-router, angular6, angular-routing

I have problem with my angular 6 app. 
For example: localhost/id/example after refresh it redirects to localhost/.
How to prevent tihs anoying behavior.

guard:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate } from "@angular/router";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

app.model.ts

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: "",
        component: DashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
      { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
      {
        path: "pacijent/:id",
        component: PacijentComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },

      {
        path: "pacijent/:id/edit",
        component: PacijentEditComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },
      {
        path: "novi-pacijent",
        component: NoviPacijentComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
      },

      { path: "**", component: NotfoundComponent }
    ])
  ],
```

i read almost every article on stack and tryed everyting but nothing helps. Its so hard to do something when its redirecting to root after every save.PLs help me :(

Comment: You mentioned page refresh and also every save? When this behavior is happening? And what save is doing.

Comment: Save in visual code studio.

Comment: I tried to replicate this issue locally but not able to replicate. Can you create a stackblitz for this.